# Lubuntu second monitor problem, windows not showing

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, freeze, lxde

I plug in a second monitor to my laptop on lubuntu 18.04 , when activating the second monitor, it is freezing on its first second and only mouse is moving around but the windows and any other changes I make don't show up.
It's like windows are invisible on the monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the problem was from open source NVIDIA drivers , installed proprietary drivers and everything is working as desired now.